# How to render a column name as a single cell in midst of multilevel columns in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm working on multilevel indexes in columns. I've to send these tables. For sending tables, I'm using `df.to_html()`. The picture below is where i am now. `foo` is the index which i've converted to column.

[image]

While converting to column, I want it to occupy both cells so it can look nice.This is what i want to achieve.

[image]

The code looks like this.

```
df = pd.DataFrame([[1, 2, 3, 4], [1, 2, 3, 4], [1, 2, 3, 4]],index=['M1','M2','M3'])
df.columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([['x', 'y'], ['a', 'b']])
ind = df.index
df.reset_index(drop=True,inplace=True)
df.insert(0,'foo',ind)
```

Comment: you would have to check documentation for `to_html` to see if it has option for this - or you will have to convert it to HTML on your own.

Answer (score 0):

With the code you provide, `foo`is not set as the index of the dataframe.

Anyway, you could add this after your current code in order to correct the header of your dataframe before converting it to html:

```py
df = df.rename(axis=1, level=0, mapper={"foo": ""}).rename(
    axis=1, level=1, mapper={"": "foo"}
)
df.to_html(index=False)
```

This way, the html version of your dataframe renders the desired way:

```
          x       y
  foo   a   b   a   b
M1      1   2   3   4
M2      1   2   3   4
M3      1   2   3   4
```